# Python decorator to refresh cursor instance

Tags: python, connection, decorator

I have a method to save data in DB, and a decorator to manage the connection, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

method to save:

```
class DA_Row(DABase):

    @DABase.connectAndDisconnect
    def save(self):
        """
        Guarda el spin en la base de datos
        """
        self.__cursor.callproc('sp_insert_row', (
                                 "value 1",
                                 "value 2"
                                 )
        )
```

and I have here the inherited class with a function decorator that does not work.

```
class DABase():

    def __init__(self):
        self.__cursor = None

    @staticmethod
    def connectAndDisconnect(func):
        def deco(*args):
            returnValue = None
            self.DBconnect()
            try:
                self.__cursor = self.db.cursor()
                returnValue = func(*args)
            finally:
                self.desconectarDB()

            return returnValue
        return deco
....
```

Shown this...

How can I redefine `DABase.__cursor` from a decorator?

If is not possible, how to solve this problem in a different way?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: the error is `self` is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self` is just a name like everything else, it does not magically appear like Java's `this`. You need to add it to your decorator. Try this:

```
    @staticmethod
    def connectAndDisconnect(func):
        # deco will be a method, so it needs self (ie a DA_Row instance)
        def deco(self, *args):
            returnValue = None
            self.DBconnect()
            try:
                self.__cursor = self.db.cursor()
                # func was supposed to be a method to, so it needs self
                returnValue = func(self, *args)
            finally:
                self.desconectarDB()

            return returnValue
        return deco
```

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you showed the error that you're getting. However, I can take a guess...

Decorating a method of a class is hard. How is `connectAndDisconnect` supposed to know what `self` should be? `connectAndDisconnect` is a *static method* of the base class, which gets called when the derived class gets created, long before any *instances* of the derived class get created.

There's a trick which lets the decorator figure out what `self` should be, but it's a complicated hack and fragile in a way that I'll explain at the end. The trick is, use a *class* as the decorator, and make that class an descriptor (i.e. define `__get__`) to give you a chance to determine what `self` should be. In your case it would look something like:

```
class DABase(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.__cursor = None

  class connectAndDisconnect(object):
    def __init__(self, method):
      self._method = method # method is the thing being decorated
                            # note that it's an *unbound* method
      self._instance = None # no way to know what the instance is yet

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
      'This will be called when the decorated method is accessed'
      self._instance = instance
      return self

    def __call__(self, *args):
      'This is where the actual decoration takes place'
      returnValue = None

      # 'self' is the connectAndDisconnect object. 'self._instance' is the decorated object.
      self._instance.DBConnect()
      try:
        self._instance.__cursor = self._instance.db.cursor()
        # Since self._method is unbound, we have to pass the instance explicitly
        returnValue = self._method(self._instance, *args)
      finally:
        self._instance.desconectarDB()
      return returnValue
```

The derived class is unchanged:

```
class DA_Row(DABase):
  @DABase.connectAndDisconnect
  def save(self):
    # ...
```

Now `DA_Row.save` is actually an instance of the `connectAndDisconnect` class. If `d` is a `DA_Row` object and someone calls `d.save()`, the first thing that happens is that `connectAndDisconnect.__get__` gets called because someone tried to access `d.save`. This sets the `_instance` variable to equal `d`. Then `connectAndDisconnect.__call__` gets called and the actual decoration takes place.

This works, most of the time. But it's fragile. It *only* works if you call `save` in the "normal" way, i.e. through an instance. If you try to do funny stuff like calling `DA_Row.save(d)` instead, *it won't work* because `connectAndDisconnect.__get__` won't be able to figure out what the instance should be.

Comment: It seems to work, it helps me understand how to work with decorators. thank you!

Comment: but is too long and confusing, it would be better a short answer for the understanding of people not that professional